# How to change tabbaritem image on a button click?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a UIButton, which when clicked, will change the tabbaritem image of that view and also, the whole view will have to be replaced with another view...

How can i be able to do this ?

Please help !

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use something like that:

```
- (IBAction)setRedTint:(id)sender {
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[keyWindow addSubview:imageView];
```

}